# Model Binding To A List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following code in my App:-

```
<tbody>
                    @{ int intCounter = 0; }
                    @foreach (var item in Model.TimeLogs)
                    {
                        intCounter++;
                        <tr>

                            <td>@intCounter</td>
                            <td>@item.EntryTypeInfo.EntryTypeName</td>
                            <td>@Html.Raw(item.TaskId == 0 ? item.Comments : "<a href=\"/Tasks/Profile/" + @item.TaskId.ToString() + "\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"Click for task profile\">" + @item.Comments + "</a>")</td>
                            <td style="text-align: right;">@item.SubTotal.ToString("c")</td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"><input id="@item.TimeLogId" class="timeLogItem" type="checkbox" data-amount="@item.SubTotal" data-timelogid="@item.TimeLogId" /></td>

                        </tr>
                    }

                    </tbody>
```

I want all these things to be binded into a list. and the checkbox I am using should return all the checked items in a collection.

How can i do this?

Regards
Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

Add a Checked property on your ViewModel then bind it to a checkbox using Html.CheckBoxFor then route the values back to your controller. At the controller, you can now query all checked items using LINQ.